# Cannot find module node:fs when using eslint-typescript-import + eslint-import-resolver-typescript + CRA

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, eslint-plugin-import

### Problem

I tried to setup path alias in my TS project, but failed to get it run. I encountered two errors when `npm start`:

- `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/App' in 'D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\src'` (even though VSC can still looked where is the location of imported files; aka no squiggly line)
- `Resolve error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'`

How I do path alias import:
`import App from "./App";` -> `import App from "~/App";`
In `tsconfig.json`: `"baseUrl": ".","paths": {"~/*": ["./src/*"]},` (full file seen below)

### Environment

- CRA with TS template
- `eslint-plugin-import@2.26.0`
- `eslint-import-resolver-typescript@3.2.5`: I added this to use path aliasing complying with above

### Files

`.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    },
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["src", "node_modules"]
      },
      "typescript": {
        "alwaysTryTypes": true,
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    // eslint rules go here ...
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules", "**/.*/"]
}
```

### Stack Trace

```
ERROR

[eslint] 
src\index.tsx
  Line 1:1:   Resolve error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Require stack:
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-typescript\lib\index.cjs
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-module-utils\resolve.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\no-unresolved.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-typescript\lib\index.cjs:5:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)  import/namespace
  Line 1:1:   Resolve error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Require stack:
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-typescript\lib\index.cjs
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-module-utils\resolve.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\no-unresolved.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-typescript\lib\index.cjs:5:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)  import/no-unresolved
  Line 1:1:   Resolve error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Require stack:
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-typescript\lib\index.cjs
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-module-utils\resolve.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\rules\no-unresolved.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-plugin-import\lib\index.js
- D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\dist\eslintrc.cjs
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\work\workbench\templates\template-fe-pure\node_modules\eslint-import-resolver-typescript\lib\index.cjs:5:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)  import/default
  Line 4:17:  Unable to resolve path to module '~/App'   import/no-unresolved

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: This is probably what cause my [error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71224407/8834000) and I suggest anyone having the same problem give this a [read](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756). You won't regret it.

Answer (score 10):

TypeScript support for the new `node:` protocol was added to [@types/node@16.0.0](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/53669) so you can try installing that. Otherwise, you can try downgrading to `eslint-import-resolver-typescript@2.7.1` which does not use the new `node:` protocol syntax.

Other than that your configuration seems fine.

Comment: I've upgraded Nodejs and it solved the issue (from ~14 to 18)

Comment: I see this issue with Node 14.17.0, but not with Node 14.21.3. Using `eslint-import-resolver-typescript@2.7.1` worked for me.

Comment: I had the problem even though I have Node 16.5.1, but downgrading to eslint-import-resolver-typescript@2.7.1 did help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I spent several hours fixing it. Finally, I detected the problem in the node version. Please upgrade it to v.16 with [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version).

Comment: Sorry it took a while answering you. But sadly, it does not worked in my situation. I fixed it sloppily by using craco and some "magic" stuff that I don't even understand myself.

Comment: I faced the same problem in node 16 :(

Comment: @misolo try updating the node version. remove all node packages and reinstall them.

Comment: I explained the problem is the node version. What's wrong?