# How to resolve missing 'fs', 'path', 'os' with react-script (no WebPack)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, react-scripts

In a frontend project:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/porton/Projects/passport_client_dfinity/node_modules/dotenv/lib'
...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/porton/Projects/passport_client_dfinity/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/porton/Projects/passport_client_dfinity/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

The [answer for WebPack is available here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161839/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-error).

But I don't use WebPack, I use plain `react-scripts`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sources": "mops sources"
  },
```

How to solve it in my case? Should I switch to WebPack?

Note that I did add

```json
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

and this does not help.

Comment: Please, also explain how to use webpack in `package.json`: For example, what should be the `"start"` script?

Comment: I realized that `react-scripts` is a wrapper over WebPack. But adding `webpack.config.js` with `resolve.fallback` does not eliminate my error messages :-~

Comment: It seems that `webpack.config.js` does not load at all, because when I intentionally make a syntax error in this file, `npm start` and `npm run build` still complaint about `fs`, `os`, and `path`, not about a syntax error in `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: When I run `webpack` directly, the (intentional) error in `webpack.config.js` does throw.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591567/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-in-react

Comment: What's your use case for using Node.js in React?

Comment: @Arkellys I use Node.js to run `react-scripts` to compile React.

Comment: What? The error you get implies you try to use Node.js *in* your React code. By default the webpack config of CRA is not configured to handle Node.js stuff, because React is browser side anyway, Node.js wouldn't work on it.