# Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\work\demo\node_modules\mime-types'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

getting error after update **"react-scripts": "4.0.3"** to **"react-scripts": "5.0.1",** let me know why I am getting this error or how can I fix this...

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\work\sams-frontend-su\node_modules\mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

also, I created a webpack.config.js file in the parent path

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") },
  },
};
```

Package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.82",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.8.0",
    "antd": "^4.20.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-window": "^1.8.7",
    "spelling": "^2.0.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does any of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206050/breaking-change-webpack-5-used-to-include-polyfills-for-node-js-core-modules) or this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20819) solve your problem?

Comment: I check it but they mention to add that fallback code under node_modules but that will not be a permanent solution if some one remove node module and again install then every time developer need to do that same process

Comment: that does not a practical solution so if we can add the webpack.config.js file in the parent and add that fallback code under that that if we can do something like this it will better soluction

Comment: or when I deploy it then the server installs node_module in a bucket and then updates webpack.config.js under node_module in local that will not work

Comment: Did you bootstrap your app with Create React App(CRA)? Your "package.json" file doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 7):

Problem is, between v4 and v5 of `react-scripts` Webpack was also updated from v4 to v5. In the past, it used to automatically polyfill Node.js modules, when imported from browser code, but this changed in v5. Now, you must explicitly inform Webpack it should use polyfills.

Your `webpack.config.js` doesn't work, because `react-scripts` ignore this file and uses the one shipped with it instead. There is a 3rd party package named `craco` (https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), which gives you possibility to patch Webpack config, but it's not marked as compatible v5, so I doubt it will work.

You can do two things then:
a) downgrade to v4 and stay there until Craco is ready for v5.
b) use browser-native library like `mime` instead

This library doesn't use any Node.js API, so it's natively supported in a browser. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The [path dependency](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/path.html) is part of the Node.js runtime.The alternative is to just use the `mime` module. This module was made to fix the issue. It uses the same data source as this module, and it has all the same mappings.

```
npm install mime
```

Ref: [Link1](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types/issues/50), [Link2](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/path.html)

Comment: I install mime but in which file do I need to add that `webpack.config.js` or `config-overrides.js` and how??

Answer (score 0):

i think you can move your packages from devDependencies to dependencies by this command

`npm i <package_name> -P`