# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in, Node js

Tags: node.js, dependencies, fs

When I run my Node.js application I always get Error: Can't resolve 'fs'.
I looked into some questions and tried to change the dependencies in my package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/vexflow": "^3.0.0",
  "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
  "jszip": "3.7.1",
  "loglevel": "^1.6.8",
  "socket.io": "^4.2.0",
  "typescript-collections": "^1.3.3",
  "vexflow": "1.2.93"
},
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: fs is a core node module, why do you need to install it?

Comment: I want the error to go away. I installed everything properly so I don't know why it can't resolve the module

Comment: can you show the complete error?

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\Florian Gogg\Documents\HTL Kaindorf\4.Klasse\SYP\KW\Project\DiSMR\node_modules\destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 13:17-30
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
 @ ./demo/index.js

Comment: The same error occours in some other index.js files in other directories too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161839/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-in

Comment: I already tried the things that were suggested in this question but that does not work either

Comment: did you try by uninstalling fs?

Comment: yes I did, and then reinstalled it but get the same error again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237670/discussion-between-goggi-and-naeem).