# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' . Read the details first

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app, package.json, node.js-fs

I've been building a basic weather api with React and TypeScript. I have utilized "npx create-react-app . typescript" for the setup. After building out my application I started it up. Initially I had success contacting the api however as I tried to save the api calls using fs.writeFile in addition to fs.readFile to collect the data I ran into the error that said it cannot resolve 'fs'.

current ts.config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "crypto": [
        "./node_modules/crypto-browserify"
      ],
    },
    "target": "ES2016",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noResolve" : false,
    "types": ["node"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude":["node_modules"]
}
```

Tried to reset using npm install --save fs.

Deleted node_modules, package.lock.json, removed "fs":  "0.0.1-security", and reinstalled. This actually seemed to work but then fs wouldn't be recognized and I reinstalled then got a new error which is progress lol.

Error with getWeather, TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).readFile is not a function
at postWeather (App.tsx:51:1)
at App.tsx:25:1

I have checked stack overflow for existing material such as [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161839/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-in).

The methods there haven't been successful and I am still searching for alternative ways but if anyone could give some advise I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The `fs` module is part of the Node.js modules, React is a frontend framework that runs on the browser, not on the Node.js runtime. Even if installing an external package for `fs` I doubt it will work, you're gonna need another way to store data on the server, say, an API.

Comment: OHHHHHH. Okay that makes sense. In that case I'll look into APIs or just remaking my next project without the React setup. Thanks Ulises!