# webpack < 5 does not include polyfills for node.js core modules

Tags: node.js, node-modules, create-react-app, webpack-5

I m running a simple create-react-app project to test out JWT Authentication. I have made a node server for both the RESTFull API and another node server for create-react-app. The server for the API is runninng just fine. However, the server for create-react-app keeps crashing with a long list of errors as such:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar'
WARNING in ../../../node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js 5:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/minimatch'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

WARNING in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/config/exec.js 20:14-63
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/version.js 16:12-54
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/index.js 6:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/index.js 7:16-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/lib/constants.js 5:4-19
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/lib/constants.js 9:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js 3:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js 4:16-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js 3:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js 4:16-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/chokidar/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/glob-parent/index.js 4:23-52
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/glob-parent'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/glob-parent/index.js 5:14-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/glob-parent'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/is-binary-path/index.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/is-binary-path'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/cli/parse.js 18:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/cli'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/cli/parse.js 19:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/cli'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/config/exec.js 1:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/config'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/config/exec.js 2:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/config'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/config/load.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/config'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/config/load.js 3:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/config'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/help/index.js 1:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/help'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/help/index.js 2:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/help'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/match.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/match.js 3:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js 2:17-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js 5:19-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js 17:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js 19:27-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/watch.js 8:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/nodemon.js 2:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/rules/parse.js 3:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/rules'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/spawn.js 1:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/spawn.js 5:14-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/utils/index.js 2:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/version.js 3:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/version.js 4:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/nodemon/lib/version.js 5:11-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/nodemon/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/picomatch/lib/constants.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/picomatch/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/picomatch/lib/picomatch.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/picomatch/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/picomatch/lib/utils.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/picomatch/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/index.js 1:13-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/pstree.remy/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/tree.js 1:14-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/pstree.remy/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/utils.js 1:14-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/pstree.remy/lib'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/readdirp/index.js 3:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/readdirp'

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/readdirp/index.js 6:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/readdirp'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ../../../node_modules/readdirp/index.js 7:16-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/reevefernandes/node_modules/readdirp'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/reevefernandes/Desktop/user-jwt/client/node_modules/.cache'

webpack compiled with 44 errors and 3 warnings
One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any time.

babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will
ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this message
go away.
```

I went thorugh the following steps as shown in these forums:

- [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161839/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-in)
- https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1670
- [How to Polyfill node core modules in webpack 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557638/how-to-polyfill-node-core-modules-in-webpack-5)

Which means, I tried to downgrade the react version and reintsall dependencies and also tapped into the webpack.config.js file to add the required, the problem still seems to persist.

What must I do?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a React.js and Firebase app and it was giving the same error. I solved my issue by removing `require('dotenv').config();`. New React.js versions automatically handles loading `dotenv` package into the files. So, if you have this line, it will give this polyfill error.

This polyfill error can be seen not just with `dotenv` package but also with some other packages you have installed.

Comment: Can you please indicate where did you remove `require('dotenv').config();` from?

Comment: `firebaseConfig.js`

Answer (score 0):

With "webpack": "^5.64.4", go to

> node-modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

under `module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {...return{..., resolve{{},//here,{}...}}}` and add all your fallbacks like`..., fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"), "async_hooks": false, "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3"), "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"), "fs": false, "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"), "http": require.resolve("stream-http"), "url": require.resolve("url/") },...`. If you export outside the main function it doesn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).